# Местоположение логики в Yii

Tags: php, yii

В моем проекте начинает серьезно расти бизнес-логика (объем кода), поэтому вопрос его правильной и удобной организации (место) в проекте достаточно остро стоит, чтобы в дальнейшем избежать дублирования кода и повысить re-usable каждой мелкой логики.

Приведу пример.

Есть контроллер и 5 action'ов. Во всех 5ти action'ах идет выборка данных, небольшая обработка на PHP и затем передача во view. "Небольшая обработка на PHP" это по сути некий алгоритм над выбранными данными.

Куда мне лучше поместить эти 5 разных алгоритмов для разных action'ов?

1. Модель? Они не имеют непосредственного отношения к данным - это лишь преобразование данных.
2. Контроллер? Контроллер должен быть thin в лучших практиках MVC.
3. View? Точно нет.
4. Component? А если будет не 5, а 50 таких action'ов? У меня папка компонентов разрастется  очень сильно - разве это хорошо?
5. Extension? Этот код очень сильно зависит от модели и не предполагает использование в других проектах.
6. Behavior модели? Ответ похож на пункт 1...
7. Widget? Может быть это лучший варинт?

Вариант с BaseModel не подходит, т.к. я использую "giix" extension, где уже есть BaseModel.

Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 2):

Эм вопрос на самом деле глупый, вся логика всегда только в контроллере. Если про разрастание этой логики и ковыряния в одном и том же контроллере становится проблематично можно сделать так.

```
class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function actions()
     {
     return  array(
     'getflights' => 'application.controllers.frontend.some.getflights', 
     'ttt' => 'application.controllers.frontend.some.ttt', 
     'getimg' => 'application.controllers.frontend.some.getimg',     
     'translate' => 'application.controllers.frontend.some.translate',         
     'getsome' => 'application.controllers.frontend.some.getsome' 
           );
      } 
}
```

Тут все fritys располагаются в отдельных файлах в отдельной папке

и выглядят так

```
class getflights extends CAction
{
  public function run()
  {
    some action
  }

}
```

Ну и все. Теперь можно и в команде разрабатывать новые экшены не трогая сам контроллер :)

И последний вопрос, архитектуру MVC понимаешь или такие вопросы рождаются при понимании этой архитектуры?

//upd

Если нужно что-то выполнять - то это все выноси в модель, если в модель нельзя то в компонент. Допустим класс для работы с куками можно в компонент вынести и юзать cookie::get(),set()delete() и т.д. на этот класс ляжет обработка кук, а в контроллере будет только логика.

Comment: А как относится к цитате "In a well-designed MVC application, controllers are often very thin, containing probably only a few dozen lines of code; while models are very fat, containing most of the code responsible for representing and manipulating the data." ( http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.best-practices )

Comment: Стоп, а причем тут этот код и цитата? Цитата написано правильно.

Тут тоже есть ряд преимуществ
1. Это то что мы можем в разных проектах использовать одинаковые контроллеры *И* часть экшенов, а ненужные просто не использовать и не копировать.

2. В контроллерах только логика, они и не обязаны знать откуда мы возьмем список пользователей и куда их выведем.

3. Вся работа с данными выносится в модели, и вот там пляшите как хотите.

Answer (score 0):

> Есть контроллер и 5 action'ов. Во всех 5ти action'ах идет выборка данных, небольшая обработка на PHP и затем передача во view. "Небольшая обработка на PHP" это по сути некий алгоритм над выбранными данными.

Выносить из контроллера надо не action, а к примеру логику получения данных, которую в свою очередь будет использовать контроллер. Эту логику предлагаю вынести в **Components** (и не обязательно всё кидать в отдельные файлы). Т.е. сюда я кидаю то, что много повторяется в action'ах.

Если же у вас идет вывод чего-то по шаблону, то на мой взгляд это должно выйти в **Widget**

> А если будет не 5, а 50 таких action'ов? У меня папка компонентов разрастется очень сильно - разве это хорошо?

Если 50 action'ов будет использовать одну схожую логику, то выносить надо эту схожую логику, а в контроллерах будет так-же 50 action'ов

Comment: Спасибо за интересный ответ, именно к этим вариантам я и склонялся.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего такую логику вынести в компоненты и их методы. Контроллеры и экшены обрабатывают http-запросы и только, логика не должна зависеть от http, например, Вы захотите использовать ту же логику в крон-скриптах. Советую что-нибудь почитать по Domain Driven Design